# Do fruit juices have a diuretic effect & what governs this?

Tags: human-biology, human-physiology, kidney

Was just contemplating this.

Juices tend to contain a lot of sugar.

1. Does the body absorb all the sugar in juices?
2. If the body does not, that sugar must be excreted by the kidneys alongside water thereby causing a diuresis, right?

NB I realise even if there is a diuretic effect that is outweighed by the large proportion of water in juices. But my question is whether there still is a small diuretic effect

Answer (score 1):

In short: Drinking fruit juice by a healthy person with a normal kidney function do not likely have any significant diuretic effect.

Even if you drink, let's say, 2 liters of 10% fruit juice within 30 minutes, it would likely take about 2 hours for all the juice to be emptied from the stomach into the intestine and absorbed into the blood. Sugar delivered from the intestine will gradually increase blood glucose, but this will be balanced by the glucose taken from the blood by the cells, so, the blood glucose will not likely exceed **11 mmol/L,** when glucose can start to move from the blood into the urine and cause diuresis.

I can back up this by the [glucose tolerance test](https://www.mayoclinic.org/tests-procedures/glucose-tolerance-test/about/pac-20394296) in which you drink 1 cup (237 mL) of a drink with ~35% glucose (>3 times as much as in a usual fruit juice). 2 hours after the test, the glucose levels in a healthy person (without diabetes mellitus) will be **lower than 7.8 mmol/L,** so below the diuretic level (11 mmol/L).